# ngx-mydatepicker is formatted as jsdate and doesn't format back to normal date angular 4

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-mydatepicker in my angular 4 application with reactive forms. I am binding date field  to input field from rest api which is in the format **"OrderDate": "2018-07-03T15:58:20.183"**. This doesn't populate date in input field directly so we need to convert it to jsdate as suggested in this post [githubissue](https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/issues/28) as in the below code snippet

`'OrderDate': [{jsdate: new Date(data.OrderDate)}, Validators.required],`

Now the date appears in the input field as expected. Now the actual problem is while submitting the form the date is coming in this format as in the below screen shot which is not accepted by rest api. So I need to convert it back to the api accepted format, how do I do it and my form contains more than 40 fields where am posting the form directly to api, so if I need to format the date I should explicitly again edit the form data before sending it to api. Is there a way that the date will format directly without explicit formatting. If there is no way then how to format back to normal date format.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the format using toISOString,

```
new Date(field).toISOString()
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)